# Laravel Before Filter in the Controller with arguments

Tags: php, filter, controller, laravel, laravel-3

I have some troubles with filters in my controller and there parameters. Maybe one of you can help me out. Thank you.
I have a controller similar to this one:

```
class Test extends Base_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();    
        $this->filter('before', 'permission:destroy|auth')->only(array('show'));        
    }
    public function action_show($id)
    {
    }
```

and I defined a filter like this:

```
Route::filter('permission', function($permission)
{
    echo $permisson;
```

If I call now the controller, the `$permission` value of my filter is the `$id` which was passed through `action_show($id)` method. But when I have a Controller Method without a paramter everything works fine. How can I always get the filter parameter instead of the method argument?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm what happens... when you add a filter to a controller, any arguments passed to the action are added to the front of the filter's arguments.  You can use `func_get_args()` to confirm that this is the case.

However, when you add a filter to a route this is not the case, the filter is run without any additional arguments.

So I can see 2 choices here, either add the filter to the route...

```
Route::get('test/(:any)', array('before' => 'permission:destroy|auth', 'use' => 'test@show'));
```

Or modify your filter to use `func_get_args()`, like...

```
Route::filter('permission', function()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $permission = array_pop($args);

});
```